# Error al ejecutar react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

Trate de iniciar un proyecto con `react-native init Proyecto` y el proyecto se crea.

Pero al momento de ejecutar: `react-native run-android` me lanza estos erroes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución?, por cierto utilizo Genymotion para emular el dispositivo android.

Comment: Seguiste los pasos de [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)? Es importante que sigas los pasos de la pestaña **Building Projects with Native Code**, en tu caso también debes elegir las opciones de Windows y Android

Comment: Si segui los mismos pasos pero arroja ese error no se por que

Comment: No estoy para nada familiarizado con Windows, pero según esta [respuesta de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922032/4914734) puedes ejecutar esto desde la carpeta de tu Android SDK `sdkmanager.bat --licenses` y aceptar las licencias (si así lo deseas claro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que al instalar/actualizar el SDK de Android, no aceptaste las licencias.

Abre Android Studio y dirígete a opciones->Appearence & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK e intenta actualizar y aceptar las licencias.